# C++ template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a class:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
class filterable_data
{
    /* ... */
};
```

I create those two instances:

```
filterable_data<int, char> a;
filterable_data<int, bool> b = a;
```

My question is, how can I write that constructor properly?

Comment: What did you try and where did you actually fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making it a template too:

```
template<typename T2, typename S2>
filterable_data(const filterable_data<T2, S2>& other);
```

Comment: It is useful and probably what the OP wants, but it's not a copy constructor. A copy constructor is never a template.